# Find min. "join" operations for sequence

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sequence

Let's say, we have a list/an array of positive integers x1, x2, ... , xn.
We can do a *join* operation on this sequence, that means that we can replace two elements that are next to each other with one element, which is sum of these elements. For example:

-> array/list: [1;2;3;4;5;6]

- we can *join* 2 and 3, and replace them with 5;
- we can *join* 5 and 6, and replace them with 11;
- we **cannot** *join* 2 and 4;
- we **cannot** *join* 1 and 3 etc.

Main problem is to find minimum join operations for given sequence, after which this sequence will be sorted in increasing order.

Note: empty and one-element sequences **are** sorted in increasing order.

Basic examples:

- for [4; 6; 5; 3; 9] solution is 1 (we *join* 5 and 3)
- for [1; 3; 6; 5] solution is also 1 (we *join* 6 and 5)

What I am looking for, is an algorithm that solve this problem. It could be in pseudocode, C, C++, PHP, OCaml or similar (I mean: I would understand solution, if You wrote solution in one of these languages).

Comment: Is this homework? What topics are you studying in class at the moment?

Comment: Interesting question, is it homework, tag it as such if it is.  If not, a use-case would be interesting.

Comment: It _was_ a homework, but few minutes ago there was a deadline (solutions should be submited online), so I am interested in solution, because I couldn't find any (solution wont't be presented in class and I am interested how to solve this problem). So, I thought I don't need to use _homework_ tag, do I?

Comment: @utyle: What topics were you studying in class? It's likely the teacher had some particular learning experience in mind when (s)he set the assignment, and it'd probably be better for you if we can show you a solution your teacher intended.

Comment: @Anon: I suppose, that my teacher thinks that every problem given as a homework is really easy, and it doesn't need any explanation... But that is ok, I'm learning self-studying ;)

Comment: @utyle, what is a size of list?

Comment: @Saeed: I think that it doesn't really matter, but if You want some boundary for input data, let's say, that array's size is < 10^4. However, I suppose that if there is an optiman algorithm, it doesn't matter, what the size is.

Comment: @Uyle, backtracking always get a optimum answer :) but for 10^4 is not good

Comment: @utyle: Please tell if you get an answer for this... it is not an easy problem, if it should be solved in non-exponential time.

Answer (score 7):

This is an ideal problem to solve using Dynamic Programming, and the recurrence described by @lijie is exactly the right approach, with a few minor tweaks to ensure all possibilities are considered. There are two key observations: (a) Any sequence of join operations results in a set of non-overlapping *summed subsequences* of the original vector, and (b) For the optimal join-sequence, if we look to the right of any summed subsequence (m...n), that portion is an optimal solution to the problem: "find an optimal join-sequence for the sub-vector (n+1)...N such that the resulting final sequence is sorted, and all elements are >= sum(m...n).

Implementing the recurrence directly would of course result in an exponential time algorithm, but a simple tweak using Dynamic Programming makes it O(N^2), because essentially all (m,n) pairs are considered once. An easy way to implement the recurrence using Dynamic Programming is to have a data-structure indexed by (m,n) that stores the results of f(m,n) once they are computed, so that the next time we invoke f(m,n), we can lookup the previously saved results. The following code does this using the R programming language. I am using the formulation where we want to find the min-number of joins to get a ***non-decreasing sequence.*** For those new to R, to test this code, simply download R from any mirror (Google "R Project"), fire it up, and paste the two function definitions (f and solve) into the console, and then solve any vector using "solve(c(...))" as in the examples below.

```
f <- function(m,n) {
  name <- paste(m,n)
  nCalls <<- nCalls + 1 
  # use <<- for global assignment
  if( !is.null( Saved[[ name ]] ) ) {
    # the solution for (m,n) has been cached, look it up
    nCached <<- nCached + 1
    return( Saved[[ name ]] )
  }
  N <- length(vec) # vec is global to this function
  sum.mn <- -Inf 
  if(m >= 1)
    sum.mn <- sum( vec[m:n] )
  if(n == N) { # boundary case: the (m,n) range includes the last number
    result <- list( num = 0, joins = list(), seq = c())
  } else
  {
    bestNum <- Inf
    bestJoins <- list()
    bestSeq <- c()
    for( k in (n+1):N ) {
      sum.nk <- sum( vec[ (n+1):k ] )
      if( sum.nk < sum.mn ) next
      joinRest <- f( n+1, k )
      numJoins <- joinRest$num + k-n-1
      if( numJoins < bestNum ) {
        bestNum <- numJoins
        if( k == n+1 )
          bestJoins <- joinRest$joins else
        bestJoins <- c( list(c(n+1,k)), joinRest$joins )
        bestSeq <- c( sum.nk, joinRest$seq)
      }
    }  
    result <- list( num = bestNum, joins = bestJoins, seq = bestSeq )
  }
  Saved[[ name ]] <<- result
  result
}

solve <- function(input) {
  vec <<- input
  nCalls <<- 0
  nCached <<- 0
  Saved <<- c()
  result <- f(0,0)
  cat( 'Num calls to f = ', nCalls, ', Cached = ', nCached, '\n')
  cat( 'Min joins = ', result$num, '\n')
  cat( 'Opt summed subsequences: ')
  cat( do.call( paste, 
                lapply(result$joins, 
                       function(pair) paste(pair[1], pair[2], sep=':' ))),
       '\n')
  cat( 'Final Sequence: ', result$seq, '\n' )
}
```

Here are some sample runs:

```
> solve(c(2,8,2,2,9,12))
Num calls to f =  22 , Cached =  4 
Min joins =  2 
Opt summed subsequences: 2:3 4:5 
Final Sequence:  2 10 11 12 

> solve(c(1,1,1,1,1))
Num calls to f =  19 , Cached =  3 
Min joins =  0 
Opt summed subsequences:  
Final Sequence:  1 1 1 1 1 

> solve(c(4,3,10,11))
Num calls to f =  10 , Cached =  0 
Min joins =  1 
Opt summed subsequences: 1:2 
Final Sequence:  7 10 11 

> solve(c (2, 8, 2, 2, 8, 3, 8, 9, 9, 2, 9, 8, 8, 7, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 9, 1, 2, 5, 1, 8, 7, 3, 3, 6, 3, 8, 5, 6, 5))
Num calls to f =  3982 , Cached =  3225 
Min joins =  30 
Opt summed subsequences: 2:3 4:5 6:7 8:9 10:12 13:16 17:19 20:23 24:27 28:33 34:42 
Final Sequence:  2 10 10 11 18 19 21 21 21 21 26 46
```

Note that the min number of joins for the sequence considered by @kotlinski is ***30, not 32 or 33.***

Comment: Isn't this an O(N^4) algorithm since there are O(N^2) states and O(N^2) work per state? You can get O(N^2 log N) by being a little more careful with the for loop inside the function `f`.

Comment: This is O(N^2) as long as you don't count calling `sum`.  Take his last example, Num calls to f = 3982 , Cached = 3225.  3982 - 3225 = 757 none cached calls to f. There are 42 elements in this set.  757 is about half of 42^2 (1764).

Answer (score 3):

[Greedy algorithm](http://spikedmath.com/320.html)!

```
import Data.List (inits)

joinSequence :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
joinSequence (x:xs) = joinWithMin 0 x xs
  where joinWithMin k _ [] = k
        joinWithMin k x xs =
          case dropWhile ((< x) . snd) $ zip [0..] $ scanl1 (+) xs
            of (l, y):_ -> joinWithMin (k + l) y $ drop (l+1) xs
               _ -> k + length xs
joinSequence _ = 0
```

At each step, grab more elements until their sum is not less than the last.  If you run out of elements, just join all the ones that remain to the prior group.

---

That was wrong.

[Combinatorial explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)!

```
joinSequence :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
joinSequence = joinWithMin 0 0
  where joinWithMin k _ [] = k
        joinWithMin k m xs =
            case dropWhile ((< m) . snd) $ zip [0..] $ scanl1 (+) xs
              of [] -> k + length xs
                 ys -> minimum [ joinWithMin (k+l) y $ drop (l+1) xs 
                               | (l, y) <- ys ]
```

Just try every possible joining and take the minimum.  I couldn't think of a smart heuristic to limit backtracking, but this should be O(n²) with [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), and O(2<sup>n</sup>) as written.

Comment: I don't have a haskell compiler, but I from your description I believe it breaks on the same example @Anon gave in a comment below: `[4, 3, 10, 11]`

Comment: OK, to be frankly, I'm no so fluent in Haskell, to understand Your code. I mean - I don't know Haskell, but I did programming some time ago in one of functional programming languages (Caml). Is it possible, that you would rewrite your code (for someone who is no-haskell-friendly) in _simpler_ version of haskell or in c, cpp, caml? (user kotlinski also wrote solution in haskell, but his code is understandable for me).

Comment: @marcog: Hmm.  I didn't see the other solution (was it deleted?) but you're right, greedy would fail there.  @utyle: The code isn't important, the concept is.  And, as marcog points out, the concept is wrong…

Comment: OK, I understand the concept, but please - show me solution's code in either _simpler_ Haskell or other lagnguage (c, cpp, php, js, java, caml). I just want to know, how to _code_ solution by myself. I would appreciate You help.

Comment: @ephemient: If You can, please write proper solution in other language, because I'm not sure if I understand code properly. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic programming approach:

Let the original array be `a[i], 0 <= i < N`.

Define `f(m, n)` to be the minimum number of joins needed to make `a[n..N-1]` sorted, such that all elements in the sorted sublist are `>` (or `>=`, if another variant is desired) the sum of `a[m..n-1]` (let the sum of an empty list to be `-inf`).

The base case is `f(m, N) = 0` (the sublist is empty).

The recursion is `f(m, n) = min_{n < k <= N s.t. sum(a[n..k-1]) > sum(a[m..n-1])} f(n, k) + k-n-1`. If no values of k are suitable, then let `f(m, n) = inf` (anything `>= N` will also work, because there are at most `N-1` joins).

Calculate `f(m,n)` in decreasing order of `m` and `n`.

Then, the desired answer is `f(0,0)`.

**EDIT**

Oops this is basically ephemient's second answer, I believe, although I am not familiar enough with Haskell to know exactly what it is doing.

Comment: What I wrote wasn't DP, but this is the idea I mentioned.  Hmm.  I'd have to think about whether this works correctly in the presence of negative integers, but if not, might as well start from 0 instead of -inf.

Comment: +1. I found this a helpful explanation.  Still can't help the feeling that there's an O(N) solution out there somewhere though...  Maybe it's possible to parameterise the problem in terms of some measure of "departure from sortedness" of the input sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Some Haskell code:

```
sortJoin (a:b:c:xs)
    | a <= b    = a : sortJoin (b:c:xs)  
    | a+b <= c  = a+b : sortJoin (c:xs)  
    | otherwise = sortJoin (a:b+c:xs)    
sortJoin (a:b:[]) = if a <= b then [a,b] else [a+b]
sortJoin a@_ = a

edits xs = length xs - length (sortJoin xs)
```

UPDATE: Made this work with test = [2, 8, 2, 2, 8, 3, 8, 9, 9, 2, 9, 8, 8, 7, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 9, 1, 2, 5, 1, 8, 7, 3, 3, 6, 3, 8, 5, 6, 5]

...now we get:

```
> sortJoin test
[2,8,12,20,20,23,27,28,31,55]
> edits test
32
```

Comment: @kotlinski: are You sure, that this will work for _every_ array? What output gives this solution for [2; 8; 2; 2; 8; 3; 8; 9; 9; 2; 9; 8; 8; 7; 4; 2; 7; 5; 9; 4; 6; 7; 4; 7; 3; 4; 7; 9; 1; 2; 5; 1; 8; 7; 3; 3; 6; 3; 8; 5; 6; 5]? (I can't run Your program right now, so I can't test its for this example array). I believe, that proper solution is 32.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. For example, consider: `[4, 3, 10, 11]`.

Comment: @kotlinski: Your solution doesn't work for [1;1;1;1;1] and similar cases.

Comment: @utyle: What's supposed to happen in the [1;1;1;1;1] case?  You want them `≤` or `<`?  (Pretty easy to fix either way.

Comment: But if You change < into ≤ then program's output for test is 33, not 32... Or maybe I don't understand, what should I change in your code...

Comment: This is a greedy approach but where is a minimality?

Comment: @utyle: My guess is that there is a misunderstanding... [1;1;1;1;1] *is* sorted in increasing order... the question did not ask for *strictly* increasing order.

Comment: @Saeed: sorry, i don't understand what minimality is :I

Comment: @kotlinski: I think he means you need a proof of why this always return the correct answer.

Comment: I mean "Main problem is to find minimum join operations for given sequence"

Comment: Looks plausible but I'd like to see a thorough explanation (or ideally a proof) that this will get the right answer every time.

Comment: Thought about it, I am relatively convinced this will *not* get the ideal answer every time - it is just a good approximation.

Comment: Counter example: for < ordering, [2,8,2,2,9,12] produces [2,8,25] - [2,10,11,12] would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully keeping it simple. Here's some pseudo-code that's exponential time.

```
Function "join" (list, max-join-count, join-count) ->
    Fail if join-count is greater than max-join-count.
    If the list looks sorted return join-count.
    For Each number In List
        Recur (list with current and next number joined, max-join-count, join-count + 1)

Function "best-join" (list) ->
    max-join-count = 0
    while not join (list, max-join-count++)
```

Here's an implementation on Clojure:

```
(defn join-ahead [f i v]
  (concat (take i v)
          [(f (nth v i) (nth v (inc i)))]
          (drop (+ 2 i) v)))

(defn sort-by-joining
  "Sort a list by joining neighboring elements with `+'"
  ([v max-join-count join-count]
     (if (or (nil? max-join-count)
             (<= join-count max-join-count))
       (if (or (empty? v)
               (= v (sort v)))
         {:vector v :join-count join-count}
         (loop [i 0]
           (when (< (inc i) (count v))
             (let [r (sort-by-joining (join-ahead + i v)
                                      max-join-count
                                      (inc join-count))]
               (or r (recur (inc i)))))))))
  ([v max-join-count]
     (sort-by-joining v max-join-count 0))
  ([v]
     (sort-by-joining v nil 0)))

(defn fewest-joins [v]
  (loop [i 0]
    (if (sort-by-joining v i)
      i
      (recur (inc i)))))

(deftest test-fewest-joins
  (is (= 0 (fewest-joins nil)))
  (is (= 1 (fewest-joins [4 6 5 3 9])))
  (is (= 6 (fewest-joins [1 9 22 90 1 1 1 32 78 13 1]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pchalasani code in F# with some modifications.  The memoization is similar, I added a sumRange function generator for sums in O(1) time and moved the start position to f 1 0 to skip checking for n = 0 in minJoins.

```
let minJoins (input: int array) =
    let length = input.Length
    let sum = sumRange input

    let rec f = memoize2 (fun m n ->
        if n = length then
            0
        else
            let sum_mn = sum m n 

            {n + 1 .. length}
            |> Seq.filter (fun k -> sum (n + 1) k >= sum_mn)
            |> Seq.map (fun k -> f (n + 1) k + k-n-1)
            |> Seq.append {length .. length}
            |> Seq.min
        )
    f 1 0
```

Full code.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

// standard memoization
let memoize2 f = 
    let cache = new Dictionary<_, _>()
    (fun x1 x2 -> 
        match cache.TryGetValue((x1, x2)) with
        | true, y -> y
        | _ -> 
            let v = f x1 x2
            cache.Add((x1, x2), v)
            v)

// returns a function that takes two integers n,m and returns sum(array[n:m])
let sumRange (array : int array) =
    let forward = Array.create (array.Length + 1) 0

    let mutable total = 0
    for i in 0 .. array.Length - 1 do
        total <- total + array.[i]
        forward.[i + 1] <- total

    (fun i j -> forward.[j] - forward.[i - 1])

// min joins to sort an array ascending
let minJoins (input: int array) =
    let length = input.Length
    let sum = sumRange input

    let rec f = memoize2 (fun m n ->
        if n = length then
            0
        else
            let sum_mn = sum m n 

            {n + 1 .. length}
            |> Seq.filter (fun k -> sum (n + 1) k >= sum_mn)
            |> Seq.map (fun k -> f (n + 1) k + k-n-1)
            |> Seq.append {length .. length} // if nothing passed the filter return length as the min
            |> Seq.min
        )
    f 1 0

let input = [|2;8;2;2;8;3;8;9;9;2;9;8;8;7;4;2;7;5;9;4;6;7;4;7;3;4;7;9;1;2;5;1;8;7;3;3;6;3;8;5;6;5|]
let output = minJoins input
printfn "%A" output
// outputs 30
```